# Opening a page and clicking results - Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Below phantomjs code attempts to open a site and click a button :

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://mysite/mypage.html', function() {
  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        $("[name='SubmitForm']").click();

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render('snap.png');
            phantom.exit();
        }, 6000); // Change timeout as required to allow sufficient time 

    });

  });
});
```

But when I run using phantomjs test.js it never returns.

How can the results page be loaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`page.evaluate()` is the sandoxed page context. It doesn't have access to variables defined outside. So using `page` or `phantom` or `require` inside of it is out of the question.

Simply move the `setTimeout` block outside of it.